# What's the simplest way to get the currently visible rows (first,last) of a QML TableView?

Tags: qt, qml

I need to access currently visible rows (first, last) from a JavaScript function, that is defined inside a TableView.

```
TableView
{
    function getVisibleRows()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I see that ListView (what is a Flickable) has a contentY property which would make the problem trivial, but TableView has not. Also, TableView is implemented in terms of a ListView, so there *is* a ListView involved, but I am not sure how to access it.
  Thank You!

Comment: By using `rowAt` maybe you could try to find out the first and last visible rows, but I guess it doesn't work when the content has not enough data to fill the view itself. Anyway, in such a case (`rowAt` returns `-1`) you can safely choose `model.count-1` as the last visible row and `0` as the first one, for they fit in the view for sure!!

Comment: Thanks but I would like to know the currently displayed (on screen) items.

Comment: good point on the model.count-1 though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out. I simply need to access `flickableItem.contentY`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the amount of rows that can be visible then you can calculate which rows are showing by using the [topRow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-tableview.html#topRow-prop) which shows which row is on the top.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [viewport property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-scrollview.html#viewport-prop) of `Scrollview` (inherited by `TableView`), which

> determines the current "window" on the contentItem. In other words, it
>   clips it and the size of the viewport tells you how much of the
>   content area is visible.

`viewport` return a complete `qml item` so you can get a lot of position data.

Comment: Could you please post an example on how to get the current scroll offset? viewport as an Item allright, but as far as I understand it just does the clipping, and unaware of current scroll position.